# Way to construct a query in which a date falls between a start and end date in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, date

The way I have it so far is:

```
select * from time where date('now') > date(start_date) and date('now') < date(end_date);
```

I was just hoping there was a short way to construct this same query. I checked the Docs for SQLite's date functions, but its hard to understand, and there isn't an obvious function that does it. If there is not a way, that is fine, but I wanted to check with expert users in SQLites ways. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is `date('now') between date(start_date) and date(end_date)` but `between` includes the end points. Depending on what `start_date` and `end_date` look like, you probably don't need to wrap them in `date()`.

Comment: Ahh, you are correct, I tested it out, but I see no point in editing it since it works either way, but thanks for letting me know. And Thanks a lot! I will try that out. Oh and you might wanna add that as an answer lol.

Comment: You can't use BETWEEN because you want `(start_date,end_date)` rather than `[start_date,end_date]` and the rest isn't really worth a whole answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TIME_TABLE 
WHERE DATE_COLUMN 
BETWEEN '01-01-2012' 
AND '12-31-2012'
```

Comment: Haha, you found this older post huh. Check out the comments under my question. "mu is too short" mentions that I can't use it because it isn't inclusive (i think thats the right word). But to be honest, with all the help you've given me, if you say it works, I believe you lol

Comment: Yeah, I should just set up an RSS feed to your questions page since I basically answer all your questions anyway :P. anyway, if you want it to be inclusive, can't you just change the dates to `12-31-2011` and `01-01-2013`?

Comment: Lmao, good idea actually. And honestly, I thought about just friending you on G+ so I can ask you there since you are being extremely helpful. But at the same time, some of my questions are bound to be of help to others getting into Android development. Oh and checkout my 2 comments on my my last question.